# How to auto start oracle listener on Linux with machine restart?

Tags: linux, oracle

I've a Linux VM with Oracle database serve and it gets restarted periodically and hence next time, oracle listener is not running. So I've to start it manually with following commands -

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export ORACLE_SID=orcl;
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start LISTENER

sqlplus
sys as sysdba/password
startup
```

This activity I've to do every time machine is restarted.

Is there a way with which oracle listener is started along with machine start? i.e. something like windows services which gets automatically started with machine start.

Comment: You asked the same question on SE.  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/286270/how-to-auto-start-oracle-listener-on-linux-with-machine-restart.  Please be patient,  This is a global forum of volunteers.  The guy with the information you seek may live 12 time zones away from you.

Comment: @EdStevens, yes henceforth I'll ask on only one forum. First I asked here and realized that on dba stackexchange I'll get answer faster  hence asked there as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of blogs and articles about how to do oracle database startup on linux upon boot, have a look [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/automating-database-startup-and-shutdown-on-linux) for an example. You can adapt this to whatever startup part you want (listener, some special database, ....)